# PHP isolate character surrounded by special character

Tags: php, database, string, sqlite

I have the following string:

```
$db_string = '/var/www/html/1_wlan_probes.db';
```

I want to isolate/strip the number character so that I only have the following left:

```
$db_string = '1';
```

So far I havn't found an simply solution since the number that needs to be found is random and could be any positive number. I have tried strstr, substr and custom functions but none produce what I am looking after, or I'm simply overlooking somehthing really simple.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function:

```
$db_string = '/var/www/html/1_wlan_probes.db';

preg_match('/html\/(\d+)/', $db_string, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]); // 1
```

`html\/(\d+)` - capture all the numbers that come right after the `html/`

You can test it out [Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db86f33a76e5e059c02c694ae9944bcc481c7860). It does not matter how long the number is, you're using a **regular expression** to match **all** of them.